# save as option missing in Access 2016

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to save an .mde file to access 2016. I opened the database using Access 2016 and I went to file menu at the top and don't see any Save as option. all I see is different options. please see below image:

[image]

I do see save under Home menu, but I can just click it and it saves the existing database. I want to convert this database to Access 2016 and rename it and then close it. the save button that I see under Home menu is shown below:

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try importing everything to new accdb file.

Comment: I don't think that this is possible, because an mde (like the newer accde) does not contain any code (at least it shouldn't).

Comment: Ok, that might be the case so I should be able to open this access database in access 2016 without any issues.

Comment: This file has likely been purposefully locked down to prevent you from saving it as a different database. Without knowing how it's been locked down, it's hard to undo it, and outside of the scope of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps

1. Click on "File" option in the Toolbar top left.
2. Now click on "Privacy Options".
3. Click on "Current Database".
4. Now in  "Options for the current database"  will open.
5. Scroll down to "Ribbon and Toolbar Options".
6. Select the checkbox "Allow Full Menus".
7. Click on "OK".
8. After step 7 you will get the pop up "You must close and reopen the current database for the specified option to take effect" Click Ok and close the MS Acess file.
9. Again open the same MS Access file Go to "File" option in the Toolbar top left. 
   10.After completing the step 9 .You will be able to see the "Save As" option.